# PHP file upload - Not checking the file size

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a file upload form from two days but cant seem to get this to work. My code is checking the extension of the file but not checking the file size. I googled, tried different methods but unable to get this to work. Can someone help?

Here's the code -

```
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['carsubmit']))
            {                            
                foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
                ${$key}=addslashes($val);

                $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); 

                $max_filesize = 2097152;

                $upload_path = "resumes/";

                $filename = $_FILES['attachresume']['name'];                    

                $file_tmp =$_FILES['attachresume']['tmp_name'];

                $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);


                $cardupcheck = "select * from `careers` where `email` = '$email'";
                $cardupresult = mysql_query($cardupcheck);

                if(mysql_num_rows($cardupresult)==1)
                {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                    notification('You have already sent us!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes)){
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                        notification('Please check the file extension. Only jpg, png and gif are allowed!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php
                    }
                    else if($file_tmp > $max_filesize){
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                        notification('too large!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php   
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"resumes/".$filename);
                        $carquery = "INSERT INTO `careers` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `aoi`, `qual`, `resume`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$aoi', '$qual', '$filename')";
                        $carresult = mysql_query($carquery);
                        if($carresult)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">         
                            notification('Thank you! We will get back to you soon!','success');
                            </script>           
                            <?php
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">         
                            notification('There was an error. Please try after some time!','error');
                            </script>  
                            <?php
                        }
                    }                                   
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php - One of which your code doesn't contain nor checks for. You will find your answer inside one of those links.

Comment: Start by looking in the error logs in whatever httpd you're using. If you're using Apache, look in /var/log/apache2/error.log and see what errors are recorded when that script is ran.

Comment: I also take it that you have a `notification()` function somewhere in your code, being unshown?

Comment: `else if($file_tmp > $max_filesize){` are you comparing max size with file name?

Comment: @Fred-ii- notification is just a javascript which shows error or success message on top of the browser.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam - No i'm not comparing. I'm checking if the file being uploaded is larger than max_filesize. I'm newbie PHP developer. Let me know the correct method.

Comment: As I said in my initial comment; check the links above I gave you. The answers are in there. You're not using size checking codes anywhere. You're just assigning a variable to a number.

Comment: I think it should be `elseif($_FILES["attachresume"]["size"] >$max_filesize)`

Comment: @Sagar Raj please don't use mysql_* functions

Comment: @Hudixt - What's the alternative to run the query and check the duplicate entries?

Comment: @Sagar Raj -  Use PDO prepared statements or use mysqli_* functions

Comment: @Hudixt - Thanks. I converted my website from mysql to mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing file size with the file name. Get the size of the uploaded file by `$_FILES["attachresume"]["size"]`.Use this code instead

```
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['carsubmit']))
            {                            
                foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
                ${$key}=addslashes($val);

                $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); 

                $max_filesize = 2097152;

                $upload_path = "resumes/";

                $filename = $_FILES['attachresume']['name'];                    

                $file_tmp =$_FILES['attachresume']['tmp_name'];

                $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
$file_size = $_FILES["attachresume"]["size"]; // Here is the size of the uploaded file

                $cardupcheck = "select * from `careers` where `email` = '$email'";
                $cardupresult = mysql_query($cardupcheck);

                if(mysql_num_rows($cardupresult)==1)
                {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                    notification('You have already sent us!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes)){
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                        notification('Please check the file extension. Only jpg, png and gif are allowed!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php
                    }
                    else if($file_size > $max_filesize){
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                        notification('too large!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php   
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"resumes/".$filename);
                        $carquery = "INSERT INTO `careers` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `aoi`, `qual`, `resume`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$aoi', '$qual', '$filename')";
                        $carresult = mysql_query($carquery);
                        if($carresult)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">         
                            notification('Thank you! We will get back to you soon!','success');
                            </script>           
                            <?php
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">         
                            notification('There was an error. Please try after some time!','error');
                            </script>  
                            <?php
                        }
                    }                                   
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Good you converted my comment as answer.I think this question is not good too because OP just made silly mistake.

Comment: @Shaiful, Hudixt - Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked -

`else if(($_FILES['attachresume']['size'] >= $max_filesize) || ($_FILES["attachresume"]["size"] == 0))`

Comment: you should not write comment as answer.